# how to scan pool of ip if port is open or not? and list it

Tags: bash

From a bash script how can I quickly find out whether a port 80 is open/listening on a server.

On all workstations is opened daemon, but sometimes it fall, how i can check all $ip from file if port is open, i use this way, but can't find how to automate it. Thank you

```
 nc 10.101.0.13 80 && echo "opened" || echo "closed"
```

I have to separate open one from closed, so i'll have a list of non working what will have to be fixed.

Comment: look up nmap - you can define a subnet to scan for a port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 sed "s/;//g" pool| while read ip string ;do  nc -zw3 $ip 80 || echo "$ip failed" >> report; done
```

`sed` will remove unwanted `;` . `while` iterates through file . `read` splits fileline and extracts ip and `nc` reports only failed ips